# CRON schedule string to start on an hour and end on a half hour

Tags: linux, cron, cronexpression

Need to schedule a job every 3 minutes from 8AM until 3:30PM. I understand how to do it from 8AM until 3PM. How to get it to continue unto 3:30PM?

Comment: @Kon: How do you know he's using Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way than going with two lines

```
*/3 8-14 * * * command
0-30/3 15 * * * command
```

Comment: See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28228106/827263).

Answer (score 5):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28227038/827263) has the right idea, but the numbers are incorrect. (Update: It was corrected ... about 8 years ago.)

This should work:

```
*/3    8-14 * * * command
0-30/3 15   * * * command
```

The first line runs `command` every 3 minutes from 8am to 2:57pm.
The second line runs `command` every 3 minutes from 3pm to 3:30pm, inclusive.

Comment: You are right, I mixed 3 with 13 and so on. I have changed it. Either way, your answer is better as my original one.